# Can't see files (created by windows) on NTFS Partition

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have a NTFS Disk that is used to share all my media files between Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Unfortunately after I saved some new videos there using Windows I can't see them in Ubuntu. It just wont "refresh" and show the new .avi files. They work pretty well in Windows.

Ubuntu Linux was hibernated and the NTFS volume mounted.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Was the file system mounted on a suspended Linux while you manipulated it with Windows or the other way around?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu was on hibernate.

Comment: Alright. Was the NTFS volume mounted in Ubuntu while it was suspended?

Comment: Yes. It was mounted

Answer (score 0):

The file system was still mounted in OS1 (Linux) while you modified it through OS2 (Windows). Since OS1 was hibernated at that time, it doesn't know about these changes. It will only know about them after umounting and re-mounting the file system.

In the future you should avoid such situations by unmounting the “shared” volume before suspension, because OS1 may unknowingly overwrite intermittent changes performed by OS2 and thus corrupt data or even the file system irreversibly.

**You must *only ever* modify a mounted file system through the directory tree below its mountpoint(s)¹.**

(¹ Some tools work on mounted file systems directly and will state so *explicitly* in their documentation.)